Does increasing max HP with Fruit Juice at a Rest Site increase how much you heal from resting?
Resting at a Rest Site restored 30% of the player's HP. Drinking a Fruit Juice potion increases max HP by 5. If you increase max HP before stopping at a rest site it increases how much you heal by resting, but Fruit Juice can be used at any time, even while at a Rest Site.
If I stop at a Rest Site then increase my max HP by drinking a Fruit Juice before resting, will it increase how much I heal from resting?

Yes, it will, with a caveat.
Fruit Juice interacts with your maximum HP. Whenever you increase your maximum HP in Slay the Spire, you also gain that much current HP.
For ease of understanding (simpler numbers) I assume you have the 'Potions give double' effect from Sacred Bark and 60/100 HP. That means this sequence of actions:
 0. Start (HP 60/100)
 1. Rest  (HP 90/100)
 2. Drink (HP 100/110)

Can give a different result from:
 0. Start (HP 60/100)
 1. Drink (HP 70/110)
 2. Rest  (HP 103/110)

Those few extra HP points mean it is generally a good idea to save your Fruit Juice until you run out of slots or encounter a campfire. Other reasons include having relics that interact with your health percentage. Gain strength (Red Skull) or HP (Meat on the Bone) at end of combat if health is below 50% are two examples. When you drink Fruit Juice, your HP percentage goes up. (In the example, from 60% to 63.6%). This may mean you miss out on the effect.
The caveat comes with the game's programming: if you're too fast clicking between the map, camp screen, and card reward screen (there is a relic that gives you cards at the campfire) then the interaction can jumble up with certain sequences and produce inconsistent and even otherwise impossible results, such as using a potion twice or not losing it when using it, or not getting any effect at all. Most regular players consider this kind of glitchy technique cheating.

Not the clearest wording, at least to me, but correct enough and the numbers help. Upvoted
